# How to randomize values in an excel cell?

Tags: excel, cell, formula

I'm trying to randomize a cell value for each cell. I want to keep the letters "tyot" at the front of the word, then randomize the 7 letters after it, which I did with this formula:

```
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))& CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&RANDBETWEEN(10,99)
```

and after joining both cells with a formula like `=A1&""&B1` I got the results that i want which it looks like this `tyotXKWAE73`. Now the next step is what i cant figure it out, which is randomizing the last six letter `"tXKWAE73"` and leaving `"tyot"`always on the front. Any ideas on how to do this last step?

Comment: So you have randomized six letters, and now you want to randomize them again?

Comment: yes correct the last ones

Comment: In a different cell? in the same cell?  Please show what you expected output should be.

Comment: If you look at this example

Comment: tyot BJZZD63          tyotBJZZD63
tyot QBAPK10 tyotQBAPK10
tyot ARRNM94 tyotARRNM94
tyot JAFHH74         tyotJAFHH74
Every sequence ends with two numbers. I want the letters and numbers to switch around like                                          
tyotBJ6ZZD3
tyotQ1APK0
tyotARR4M9
tyotJA7HH4

Comment: but always keep tyot on the front

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomize word in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557364/11683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following functions in a standard module:

```
Public Function Shuffle(s As String) As String
    Dim ary(1 To 7) As String, ndex(1 To 7)
    For i = 1 To 7
        ary(i) = Mid(s, i, 1)
        ndex(i) = i
    Next i
    Call Shuffle2(ndex)
    Shuffle = ""
    For i = 1 To 7
        Shuffle = Shuffle & ary(ndex(i))
    Next i
End Function

Public Sub Shuffle2(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

Then in **B1** enter:

```
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)) & CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))& CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&RANDBETWEEN(10,99)
```

In **B2** enter:

```
="tyot" & shuffle(B$1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Each entry in column **B** is a "randomization" of **B1** with a fixed prefix.